# Images not showing up in published Tableau dashboard when using URL actions

Tags: image, action, dashboard, tableau-api

Good day,

I have created a simple URL action that loads an image when one clicks on a name. I have a dashbaord with two sheets and an webpage between them. The first sheet shows the stats of a particular name. The second sheet is a table of names being used as a filter to control what stats and webpage are shown. The webpage is an image link that shows a picture that corresponds to the name. I am using an URL action that pulls the full image link from the data file.

When I create the dashboard on my own computer the images show up with no issues. However, when I published online through Tableau Public the images do not show up. I am not getting an 'X' or 'image not found' error but just a blank white square.

Does this have something to do with the version I am using (Tableau 8.2 Public Professional Edition) or is there an another issue I am not realizing.

Any guidance would be most appreciated.

Cheers.

Paul

Comment: What is the link to the dashboard on Tableau Public?

Comment: The link to the dashboard is here:

https://public.tableausoftware.com/views/poke_temp/Dashboard1?:showVizHome=no#1

I should also mention. The images show up in Safari when viewed on an iPhone or Mac. They just do not show up on Windows platforms (tested in Chrome, IE, and FireFox).

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this is an issue with embedding non-secure (**http**) URLs on a site with **https** (tableau public runs on **https**://public.tableausoftware.com).

I created a calculated field that changes your URL value from:

http://img.pokemondb.net/artwork/abomasnow.jpg

to

https://img.pokemondb.net/artwork/abomasnow.jpg

You can see the calc in the workbook, it is: `replace([Img], "http", "https")`

See: https://public.tableausoftware.com/shared/7XQBNZCBX?:display_count=no

Comment: you should use http: and replace with https: in case there are any https already there. But nice :)